# Convert datetime to timestamp in Neo4j

Tags: datetime, neo4j, timestamp, neo4j-apoc

How to convert datetime in data loaded in Neo4j to timestamp?
Example datetime format: 2020-04-07T12:39:38.027Z
Please assist.

Comment: DateTime is a datatype.  Timestamp field is used to record the instant when an event occurred.  Timestamp field can be of any datatype such as DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4's temporal instants (like `datetime`) have a special variable, [epochMillis](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-temporal-instants), that provides the equivalent epoch time.

For example:

```
RETURN datetime('2020-04-07T12:39:38.027Z').epochMillis
```

returns

```
1586263178027
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a DateTime to a string by first converting it to a timestamp with [epochMillis](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-temporal-instants) and passing that to the [`apoc.date.toISO8601`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.date/apoc.date.toISO8601/) function.

```
WITH datetime() as dt
RETURN apoc.date.toISO8601(dt.epochMillis, "ms") AS iso8601
```

returns

```
"2022-04-30T18:56:53.145Z"
```